# XmlSlurper parseText - node name replace with variable

Tags: java, groovy, xml-parsing, xmlslurper

Parsing the XML response, I'm declaring all the node's name in an array list `myTag`, and call the API endpoint and get the XML response text and stored in `xmlResult`.

then I looping all the node values and get the node text.

my code

```
def myTag =['appNo','date','name']

def xmlResult = new XmlSlurper().parseText(responseObject.getResponseText())

myTag .eachWithIndex({ def item, def index ->
    def readableTag = myTag.get(index)  
    def result = xmlResult.application.$readableTag.text()
    println result
})
```

I'm getting the empty result for all the nodes with the above looping, but when I use the below I'm getting the result.

```
def result = xmlResult.application.appNo.text()
def result1 = xmlResult.application.date.text()
def result2 = xmlResult.application.name.text()
```

Let me know how can I pass the node value from variable and how can I replace with the variable value in the above statement?

Answer (score 1):

I got the answer, passing the variable within the double quote.

```
myTag .eachWithIndex({ def item, def index ->
    def readableTag = myTag.get(index)  
    def result = xmlResult.application."${readableTag}".text()
    println result
})
```